# How to get upper and lower bounds of objective vector in gurobi R

Tags: r, linear-programming, gurobi

I'm trying to get the upper and lower bound vectors of the objective vector that will keep the same optimal solution of a linear program.  I am using gurobi in R to solve my LP.  The gurobi reference manual says that the attributes SAObjLow and SAObjUP will give you these bounds, but I cannot find them in the output of my gurobi call.

Is there a special way to tell the solver to return these vectors?

The only values that I see in the output of my gurobi call are status, runtime, itercount, baritercount, nodecount, objval, x, slack, rc, pi, vbasis, cbasis, objbound.  The dual variables and reduced costs are returned in pi and rc, but not bounds on the objective vector.

I have tried forcing all 6 different 'methods' but none of them return what I'm looking for.

I know I can get these easily using the lpsolve R package, but I'm solving a relatively large problem and I trust gurobi more than this package.

Here's a reproducible example...

```
library(gurobi)
model = list()
model$obj = c(500,450)
model$modelsense = 'max'
model$A = matrix(c(6,10,1,5,20,0),3,2)
model$rhs = c(60,150,8)
model$sense = '<'

sol = gurobi(model)
names(sol)
```

Ideally something like SAObjLow would be one of the possible entries in sol.

Answer (score 0):

Not all attributes are available in the Gurobi R interface - this includes the ones for sensitivity analysis.
You may find [this example](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/sensitivity_r.html) helpful.

Alternatively, you can use a different API, like Python, to query all available information.

Comment: That's a bummer.  Thanks!